# Combine array in php

Tags: php, arrays

**I have array**

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      2 => int 50000
  1 => 
    array
      2 => int 30000
  2 => 
    array
      1 => int 25000
  3 => 
    array
      1 => int 20000
  4 => 
    array
      1 => int 10000
```

**I need to create array the result is:**

```
array
  2 => int 50000
  2 => int 30000
  1 => int 25000
  1 => int 20000
  1 => int 10000
```

Thank for all.
sorry, my english very bad :(

Comment: You can't, because in PHP an array cannot have the same key more than once. You would just end up with `array(2 => 30000, 1 => 10000)`

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't allow arrays to have the same keys. This will show how php will handle a foreach loop wich is rewriting the array into a new one with desired key and value

```
$array = array(
  0 => 
    array(
      2 => 50000),
  1 => 
    array(
      2 => 30000),
  2 => 
    array(
      1 => 25000),
  3 => 
    array(
      1 => 20000),
  4 => 
    array(
      1 => 10000)
);

$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $data)
{
    foreach($data as $key => $val)
    {
        $new_array[$key] = $val;
    }
}
var_dump($new_array);
```

This will output

```
array(2) {
  [2]=>
  int(30000)
  [1]=>
  int(10000)
}
```

[Live Sample](http://ideone.com/jKJLAY)

As you can see keys are overwritten on each loop becuase they are identical and so are values, i think you can use the above function to have a one level array removing keys from `$new_array`

```
foreach($data as $key => $val)
{
    $new_array[] = $val;
}
```

[Live Sample](http://ideone.com/djPmFs)

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want (without preserving children keys, since you cannot have multiple elements with the same key):

```
$flat_array = array_map('current', $array);
```

Try here: http://codepad.org/1h7mKbqe

Comment: Where is the same key!? Array
(
    [0] => 50000
    [1] => 30000
    [2] => 25000
    [3] => 20000
    [4] => 10000
)

Comment: That's a simple way to get first element, +1